# Reading 100 csv files and writing and save the overall mean, SD, Max,Min, and quantile (5,15,85,90%)

Tags: r

I need to write a code can read 100 csv ( names from "sc01" to "sc100") files and extract some basic statistics and save the overall ( for each column of each file) e.g. Mean, SD, Max,Min, and quantile (5,15,85,90%).
I have two locations so I filtered them based on the X positions:

```
For location 1
 Data1<- select(filter(exprs_data,XPos>= -2562 & XPos<= -2060),c(4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,16,19,20,25,26,27))
#Calculate 5,15,80,85,90,and 95 percentiles
Per=apply(Data1[],2, quantile, probs=c(0.05, 0.15,0.80, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95))

#For location 2
Data2<- select(filter(exprs_data,XPos>= -2562 & XPos<= -2060),c(4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,16,19,20,25,26,27))
per1=apply(Data2[],2, quantile, probs=c(0.05, 0.15,0.80, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95))
```

I need to loop over each file of the 100 files and get the above data for each column then save all of the data in CVS file. Thanks

Comment: # For location 2

Comment: correction of location 2 coordinates : (XPos>= -748 & XPos<= -247)

Comment: Feel free to edit your question, that will make it easier to see your updates than the comments.

Comment: There are a variety of tutorials online that demonstrate "read a directory of CSVs into R, do something with each, save it." I like using `purrr` for this like https://www.gerkelab.com/blog/2018/09/import-directory-csv-purrr-readr/ or https://www.mjandrews.org/blog/readmultifile/